# friendly-id: Undefined method slug for Movie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, slug, friendly-id

I downloaded the friendly_id gem in order to make my URLs more user friendly. To honor their instructions, I am asking this here instead of on GitHub.

Here is my Show Method

```
def show
  @movie = Movie.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is in compliance with their documentation

```
Finders are no longer overridden by default. If you want to do friendly finds, you must
do Model.friendly.find rather than Model.find. You can however restore FriendlyId 
4-style finders by using the :finders addon:
```

In my Model.rb file, I have the following

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

From their documentation

```
friendly_id :foo, use: :slugged # you must do MyClass.friendly.find('bar')
```

also from their documentation

```
def set_restaurant
  @restaurant = Restaurant.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

For reference, here is their guide.

Granted, I haven't generated a migration yet, because I had already created the table.

I'm unsure of what my next step should be?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: As the docs say, you need a `slug` column

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check out the video

Answer (score 16):

You need to run a migration to add the slug column to your table:

```
class AddSlugToMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :movies, :slug, :string, unique: true
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate`, and then in your rails console run `Move.find_each(&:save)` to populate the slug column.

Comment: It's really surprising to me that this isn't (as far as I can tell) in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: It's kind of in there: `rails generate scaffold user name:string slug:string:uniq`

Answer (score 2):

Marina is correct that you have to add `slug` field.

But lot's of people got confused because FriendlyID generates `friendly_id_slugs` table which contains sluggable_id and sluggable_type field.

```
create_table "friendly_id_slugs", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "slug",                      null: false
t.integer  "sluggable_id",              null: false
t.string   "sluggable_type", limit: 50
t.string   "scope"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type", "scope"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type_and_scope", unique: true
t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type"
t.index ["sluggable_id"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_id"
t.index ["sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_type"
end
```

Basically it generates friendly_id_slugs table for History Module.
Have a look at their documentation about **History__Avoiding_404_s_When_Slugs_Change** : http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#History__Avoiding_404_s_When_Slugs_Change

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting started with a **new table** you can also do this:

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movies do |t|
      ...
      t.string :slug
      t.index :slug, unique: true, using: :btree
    end
  end
end
```